# devtool clones the wrong repository for recipe development

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I am using `krogoth` and recently I have been observing that everytime I do the following:

1. Add a recipe

   ```
   devtool add buttonflux https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/buttonflux/archive/v1.0.tar.gz
   ```

I get the a previous recipe which I worked up.

here is the `recipe-tool` generated recipe of the above repository:

```
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)
#
# WARNING: the following LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM values are best guesses - it is
# your responsibility to verify that the values are complete and correct.
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=7e8b8d2e60aca564edd8578b5f1f4951"

HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/bnoflux"
SUMMARY = "Extract IMU Values from BNO055 and store them in InfluxDB via UDP"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/buttonflux/archive/v${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "1c897adf29ed058315d23d3a79f9c532"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "1c5611a579ee169a611fc5b401eb1aa6ad8cb4c168722df0dba7d61bb8fd2d2b"

S = "${WORKDIR}/bnoflux-${PV}"

inherit setuptools

# WARNING: the following rdepends are from setuptools install_requires. These
# upstream names may not correspond exactly to bitbake package names.
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python-influxdb"

# WARNING: the following rdepends are determined through basic analysis of the
# python sources, and might not be 100% accurate.
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python-argparse python-core python-logging"

# WARNING: We were unable to map the following python package/module
# dependencies to the bitbake packages which include them:
#    influxdb.client
#    smbus
```

It is worth noting the the `HOMEPAGE` is false and so are the `SRC_URI` hashes. (I want to use `buttonflux` and not `bnoflux` which was my previously worked upon recipe)

I tried reseting the recipes but this problem is still persistent.

my `workspace` clones also the wrong repository:

```
workspace/
├── appends
│   └── buttonflux_1.0.bbappend
├── attic
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── README
├── recipes
│   └── buttonflux
│       └── buttonflux_1.0.bb
└── sources
    └── buttonflux
        ├── bin
        │   ├── bnoflux
        │   └── calibrate
        ├── bnoflux
        │   ├── BNO055.py
        │   ├── bnoflux.py
        │   ├── calibrate.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── LICENSE
        ├── MANIFEST.in
        ├── README.md
        └── setup.py
```

even though the `source` is called `buttonflux` the code within it belongs to `bnoflux` repository.

I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: devtool stuff is quite recent, so I suggest you upgrade Yocto version, at least to see if your problem still occurs?

Comment: @Nayfe as much as I like to transition, I cant since the BSP for the Board is based on `krogoth`. I tried transitioning to `rocko` but my builds have been failing miserably

Comment: What does contain the .bbappend file?

Comment: I already removed the workspace. I will try to reproduce the error and see what the content of the `.bbappend` file is